# Rails Ajax CRUD: Update is PUTing to "/models" and not "/model/:id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form partial that is rendered on a page:

```
<%= form_for @shift, :remote => true, :html => { :id => 'entry_form' } do |f| %>
... entry fields ...
<%= f.submit %>
```

The other partial rendered on the page is a list of the shifts for that day. Create and Delete work just fine, and are pretty standard. For instance, I use the simplest Ajax approach for create:

```
page.replace_html('listing', render(:partial => 'listing', :object => @schedule ))
```

(Note @schedule has_many @shifts)

The issue arises with Edit and Update. Hitting 'Edit' would effectively populate my form partial with Ajax, but when I hit 'Update Shift,' I am met with the following error:

```
Started POST "/shifts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-21 20:03:10 -0700
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/shifts"):
```

Obviously, this POST (or rather PUT) should be committing to 'shift/:id.'

Here's what I discovered: If I made my 'Edit' link non-remote, the proper HTML is created and the update works:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/tours/290" class="edit_tour" data-remote="true" id="entry_form" method="post">
```

BUT, when I make 'Edit' remote, the form looks like it's making a new object, even though the fields are properly populated and the button reads 'Update Shift':

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/shifts" class="new_shift" data-remote="true" id="entry_form" method="post">
```

Here's my edit.js.rjs:

```
 page.replace_html('entry_form', render(:partial => 'shift_entry', :object => @schedule ))
```

And inside my controller:

```
def edit
  @shift = Shift.find(params[:id])
end
```

`@schedule` is set in my application controller. It appears my update.js.rjs isn't even being called. I'm using prototype.

Any ideas? I'm really stumped on this one. Thanks!

**Edit:**

A bit more info. Here's what my form header looks like when it's rendered with @shift = Shift.new (create):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/shifts" class="new_shift" data-remote="true" id="entry_form" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="KwY8w4l6qgKs6T3aMW8EUvl7V9I38HO8mz+QadBXKig=" /></div>
```

The header for the original (broken) edit is above. When I force :method => :put and try an 'Edit' -> 'Update', nothing changes (except my Create action breaks) and it looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/shifts" class="new_shift" data-remote="true" id="entry_form" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="KwY8w4l6qgKs6T3aMW8EUvl7V9I38HO8mz+QadBXKig=" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add :method => :put inside of your :html options in your form_for line.

Should look like this:

```
<%= form_for @shift, :remote => true, :html => { :id => 'entry_form', :method => :put } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error-it appears that makes no difference for an Update. And I'm trying to use this form for both updates and creates, so that setting breaks my create action.

Comment: Would you mind posting the HTML that is generated for the form? I'm just curious what is generated, because you need to have a hidden field inside of the form to do a put, since PUT is not a real HTTP verb. I have always needed to do :method => :put in order to get update to work.

Comment: Not at all, I just added some of the output to the original post. Let me know if you need more info from me

Comment: There is a fairly significant change that occurs to your form. You have an extra hidden field when you do :method => :put which is why your create breaks. If you are using resources in your routes, I'm pretty sure you have to do :method => :put in your form. The only other thing I can think of is to add :url => edit_shift_path(@shift) instead. Not :url is its own thing, it does not go inside of the :html hash.

Comment: No luck with adding the :url. Thanks for all your help, it looks like there must be a core flaw somewhere. I'll try sleeping on it and looking at it with a fresh pair of eyes tomorrow and post back if I discover anything.